# Django model reference and data update/insert

Tags: django, string, django-models, insert

I have some models defined in **models.py** (just a subset)

```
class arctic_seasons(models.Model):
    season_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    season_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.season_name

class antarctic_seasons(models.Model):
    season_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    season_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.season_name
```

Notice that the only difference between these tables is the prefix **arctic_** or **antarctic_**

I am defining a view that will essentially decode some GeoJSON data and insert it into the database based on the models.

The GeoJSON has a string parameter 'season' which will identify which model (table) the data should be inserted into.

For example say we end up with these variables (pulling from GeoJSON collected in POST)

```
season = data['properties']['season']
location = data['properties']['location']
```

If **season = '2011_Greenland_P3'** and **location = 'arctic'** the view should insert a new season into arctic_seasons with season_name = '2011_Greenland_P3'

Essentially it should do"

```
s = arctic_seasons(name=season);
s.save()
```

My question is, how do I write a code that can handle the variable location prefix. If the location were 'antarctic' the statement would become:

```
s = antarctic_seasons(name=season);
s.save()
```

However I obviously don't want to duplicate all of this code. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just update your models

```
LOCATION = (('Arctic', 'Arctic'), ('Antarctic', 'Antarctic'))

class Season(models.Model):
    season_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    season_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    location = models.CharField(choices=LOCATION)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s-%s"%(self.location, self.season_name)
```

and pass in the appropriate argument.

```
s = arctic_seasons(name=season, location='Arctic');
s.save()
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this should work out. It requires a bit of logic change in my system design but I think it will work out better. A few quick questions. 1. What is ChoiceField stored as in the database? 2. Can you query based on location. Say "SELECT * FROM Season where location='arctic';"

Comment: You could do something differnt. ill update the model - Yes you can query it the way you mentioned. Also, now it is a simple charfield